# Where is this terminal?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I have to activate the terminal for the Hanar Diplomat quest, but I can't seem to find it?  The only terminal I can find in the security checkpoint area (I'm standing next to it on the map) cannot be interacted with.

[image]

Comment: I don't know for certain, but try looking on the left side as you come out of the elevator (you seem to be looking to the right)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That terminal's about halfway down the hallway between the elevator and the first of two security grids.  Coming from the elevator, I believe it's on the left hand side.

Looking at your screenshot, on the map it's to the right of you; if you back out of the map you'd want to look to your left.  It's on the wall between two red couches.

It should be highlighted with a circle when you approach it - if not, you might have missed a previous terminal or there could be some other issue.

**UPDATE**: Some users are reporting that the quest is potentially [bugged](https://web.archive.org/web/20160318002159/forum.bioware.com/topic/269788-citadel-hanar-diplomat-bugged/) - make sure if you start this mission that you run it through to completion before doing anything else!

Comment: I remember it being on the left as you exit the elevator.

Comment: that terminal is definitely not the one, can't interact with it at all, is there a second terminal in the security checkpoint area?

Comment: it has to be in this area as there are no other terminals that show up in my map when I am in any other zone on the citadel

Comment: @yx., it sounds like this quest might be bugged.  Check my link for more details from other users having the same problem as you.

Comment: yea, looks like my quest is bugged :(